# How to run this bash code on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, kernel, osdev

I have some code I cloned from GitHub https://github.com/chipsetx/Simple-Kernel-in-C-and-Assembly which is a simple version of a boot loader in assembly and a kernel written in c language. My goal is to reverse engineer it, learn from it and then eventually write my own boot loader and kernel. Im running macOS Monterey and have gcc installed. ld linker is installed too. The problem is the instructions too compile the code is for linux. Ive gotten as far as to compile it but when it reaches certain line of bash it says "ld: warning: option -m is obsolete and being ignored" "file not found: elf_i386" this code segment complains. Below is the line of code that's giving me problems. Can you please help find a way to compile this code for macOS. I would highly appreciate it.

line giving me problems on Mac

```
 ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```

Here's the bash code from the GitHub repository

```
nasm -f elf32 kernel.asm -o kasm.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kc.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel
```

Comment: MacOS uses an LLVM based tool chain and the options aren't compatible with ELF formats. By default MacOS uses Macho/Macho64 object formats. The easiest thing to do is build or install an i386 or i686 GCC cross compiler. That will give you a version of GCC/G++/LD etc that can be used for OS development. Otherwise you'd have to spend the effort to coerce the MacOS tools to do the same thing.

Comment: If you can use `brew` you should be able to do `brew install i686-elf-gcc`

Comment: I replaced ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o with ld -m elf_i686 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o and it didn't work.

Comment: I never told you to use `-m elf_i686` (which isn't a thing). I said you'd need to install a 386 or 686 cross compiler. Once installed you'd actually use `i686-elf-ld` and `i686-elf-gcc` rather than `ld` and `gcc` of your system.